# Where to install kernel header for BeagleboneBlack 3.8.13-bone79?

Tags: header-files, kernel-module, beagleboneblack

I'm currently using the default OS on eMMC of BeagleBone Black but I found no header files in `/src/usr path`. I tried to install via apt-get install and official website of Derek Molloy but it is dead already. I'm wondering can anyone give me the header files or provide me with some other sites where I can install? I need it to build Makefile and compile.

The version I'm using is 3.8.13-bone79.

Answer (score 0):

That is a heavily outdated version of the default Debian install. I'd strongly suggest reinstalling a current image on the BBB from here: http://beagleboard.org/latest-images

There is no reason to stick to this old and problem-riddled install.